# Questions about poles

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity-theory

Find order of pole for $$f(z)=\frac{1}{e^{z}-1}$$ at $z=0$.

Now I turned the function into this: $$\frac{1}{\sum_{1}^{\infty}x^k/k!}$$

I think the pole has order $1$ but $\lim(z(f(z)))$ seems to be $1$, this is why I was confused. That limit should be $0$ according to our definition of order of a pole.

Comment: Surely $g(z)=1/z$ has a pole of order one at the origin. So “our definition” is clearly wrong.

Comment: So theh lim(z-z0)^(m+1)f(z) where m is the order of the pole does not equal 0?

Comment: Ah I get it now, that is why the power is m+1 and not m.

Comment: if the pole is order 1, use $z^2$

Answer (score 1):

You can come up with a Laurent expansion by performing polynomial long division:

$$\frac{1}{z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots}=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{z}{12}-\frac{z^3}{720}+\cdots$$

The order of the pole one...

Comment: This is my way of doing it, but it’s really “power-series division”, ’cause you write the terms in ascending order of degree rather than descending.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{e^z-1}=\frac{1}{\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{e^z-e^0}{z-0}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$e^z - 1$ is of the form $zh(z)$ with $h(0) = 1$. You have
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{h(z)} \frac{1}{z} \sim \frac{1}{z} \quad \text{ as $z \to 0$}.$$
Therefore the pole has order $1$.